# php code to reverse a string using paramaterized function

Tags: php

Below is my Code to Reverse a String..

The code runs well but I need to wrap this code inside Paramaterized function
 in which user pass a string inside function and get return output.

```
<?php
$string = trim("This");
$len =strlen($string);
$stringExp = str_split($string);
for ($i = $len-1; $i >=0;$i--)
{
echo $stringExp[$i];
}
?>
```

for Ex -
I want above string reversal code logic like below function...

```
<?php
$str = "rahul";
echo reverse($str);

function reverse($str)
{
    for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($str) - 1; $i < $j; $i++, $j--) {
        $tmp = $str[$i];
        $str[$i] = $str[$j];
        $str[$j] = $tmp;
    }

    return $str;
}
?>
```

Comment: you know there is a build in function: `strrev()` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

Comment: yes i know but i want this using loop...and exactly only the above code need to be wrapped inside function.....

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Isn't the wheel round enough yet, or are you just looking for ways to slow down your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try this

```
$str = "rahul";
echo reverse($str);

function reverse($str)
{
    $tmp = '';
    for($i = (strlen($str)-1);$i >= 0; $i--) {
        $tmp .= $str[$i];
    }

    return $tmp;
}
```

Comment: @Robert except the variables :P

Answer (score 0):

There is strev() function which does it but if you need write your own here is the code

```
$str = "abcde";

function reverse ($str)
{
    $output = '';
    for ($i = strlen($str)-1; $i >= 0 ; --$i) {
      $output .= $str[$i];
    }

    return $output;
}


echo reverse($str);
```